# I uninstalled python (uh oh) and my new install is in a different location, can i move it back to /usr/bin/local?

Tags: python, installation, scipy, bash

I lashed out at python and got rid of it on my Mac which was obviously very stupid.

Now i want to repair the damage. `which python` gives `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python`

But i think it used to be in `/usr/bin/python`?

Certainly when running http://fonnesbeck.github.io/ScipySuperpack/ for OS X 8 i get this error repeated for all the installations

```
Installing Scipy Superpack ...
sudo: /usr/bin/python: command not found
```

Is there an easy way to get python back in /usr/bin, perhaps something in the /.bash_profile?

Btw I sudo cp'd it but `which python` still gives the above.

Comment: `ln -s` to create a symbolic link may be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried repairing the OS with the install disk? I wonder if that would re-install Python 2.7 back on, since it's part of the system.

Comment: That is a great idea, i'll look for the disk and let you know

Comment: What OS are you on? I can't remember if it was 10.7 or 10.8 that introduced the recovery partition on your drive, so you might not even need the disk. If you boot your computer and hold Option (or Alt, depends what your keyboard says), you might see "Recovery Partition" or similar, that can do the repair as well I believe.

Comment: 10.8. This is great thanks, especially because i couldn't find the disk. Says it takes 2 hours, then I'll let you know if python is back.

Comment: Great, the 2 hours is because it's downloading the OS again to repair, so keep your internet connection running!

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't restore the old pythons but thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could install python from [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/)

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
brew install python
```